# Problem with Lightning Design System (SLDS) Notification component on vf page

Tags: slds

I'm building a mobile VF page using SLDS and I'm trying to display success and error messages using the SLDS Notification component (slds-notify_container). When I add it to my page, it incorporates the text from a completely separate `<div>` below it AND it doesn't render at the proper width on a mobile device (it doesn't scale down to fit the smaller window in other words). I don't see anything in the SLDS docs about having to specify width. Has anyone used the SLDS Notifications component? I haven't found any examples out there that show the Notification component in use.

Comment: Can you share you're html code?